# Log4j pattern layout %p token not working

Tags: java, log4j

According to log4j documentation on the PatternLayout class, it has the following snippet:

> In the example above the conversion specifier %-5p means the priority of the logging event should be left justified to a width of five characters.

I wanted to just have a single character as the log priority identifier, such as "DEBUG" becoming "D", "ERROR" becoming "E" and so on.

In order to try and achieve this, I created the following PatternLayout:

```
consoleAppender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{[dd/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss]} :: [%1p] :: %C{1} : %M :: %m%n"));
```

The above code gives me the following logging format:

> > [22/11/2013 09:18:54] :: [INFO] :: RAMJobStore : initialize :: RAMJobStore initialized.

Is there something in particular I am doing wrong? The documentation seems to make this sound simple, unless this functionality is broken in log4j 1.2.16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [EnhancedPatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html) there is new pattern token to achieve this: `%level{length=1}`.

Your pattern:

> %d{[dd/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss]} :: [%level{length=1}] :: %C{1} : %M :: %m%n

[Online test for this pattern](http://log4jtester.com/?p=%25d%7B%5Bdd%2FMM%2Fyyy%20HH%3Amm%3Ass%5D%7D%20%3A%3A%20%5B%25level%7Blength%3D1%7D%5D%20%3A%3A%20%25C%7B1%7D%20%3A%20%25M%20%3A%3A%20%25m%25n)

Comment: In log4j2 you can also set unique names to levels: %level{WARN=W, DEBUG=D, ERROR=E, TRACE=T, INFO=I, FATAL=F} test:
http://log4jtester.com/?p=%25level%7BWARN%3DW%2C+DEBUG%3DD%2C+ERROR%3DE%2C+TRACE%3DT%2C+INFO%3DI%2C+FATAL%3DF%7D+%25m%25n

Answer (score 1):

It's not broken.

You are trying to write the priority in a field of one character.  The value of the priority in your case is "INFO", a four-letter string.

The documentation says:

> If the data item is larger than the minimum field width, the field is expanded to accommodate the data.

So you asked to format in a field with of 1 character, but it expanded to 4.

Comment: Ah yes...that it is. I knew what I was trying to do, although I didn't see that part of the documentation. Thanks!